# How to install build dependencies directly from the debian/control file?

Tags: dependencies, controls, package, debian, apt

I have a Debian source package, it contains a standard debian/control file, which lists a "Build-Depends:" field.

How can I install those build depends without a lot copy and paste?

The package is not in Debian repository. So apt-get build-dep won't work.

Answer (score 45):

Try mk-build-deps from [devscripts](https://packages.debian.org/sid/devscripts) package.

```
mk-build-deps --install <controfile>
```

PS: Make sure you have package [equivs](https://packages.debian.org/sid/equivs) installed also.

Comment: Is it possible to do this non-interactively? e.g. `--yes`?

Comment: Override the default tool: `mk-build-deps --install --tool='apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes --no-install-recommends --yes' debian/control`